# Excel's ColorIndex VBA convert to HTML colors

Tags: html, excel, vba, charts, colors

I have working code that changes a Charts colors based from conditional formatting cell colors.

Only thing is that when it applies the color to the chart, it takes the ColorIndex property which is limited to Excels 56 color palette. The chart I have then looks like a children's birthday party and doesn't look as classy as the billion RGB colors.

Is there a way to pull the RGB color codes and apply that to the chart? I can do It manually to any color I want, but I want it to be all automated.

```
Sub ColorChartColumnsbyCellColor()

Dim xChart As Chart
Dim I As Long, xRows As Long
Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set xChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
If xChart Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

With xChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    Set xRg = ActiveSheet.Range(Split(Split(.Formula, ",")(1), "!")(1))
    xRows = xRg.Rows.Count
    Set xRg = xRg(1)
    For I = 1 To xRows
        .Points(I).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(xRg.Offset(I - 1, 4).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Interior.ColorIndex > RGB is that's possible?

Comment: Use `xRg.Offset(I - 1, 4).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` directly

Comment: When I use that ^^

I get a runtime error:

"Method 'colors of object' _Workbook" Failed 

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the Colors part. It's just: `.Points(I).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = xRg.Offset(I - 1, 4).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`

Comment: DUUUDEEE You've helped me out so much. Is there a rating system here, Can I give you a star or something ?

Comment: I've posted it as an answer below so you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
.Points(I).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = ThisWorkbook.Colors(xRg.Offset(I - 1, 4).DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex)
```

with this:

```
.Points(I).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = xRg.Offset(I - 1, 4).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```